# Incubation time of Antarctic Phosphatase in lab

Tags: genetics

Antarctic Phosphatase is used to catalyze the removal of 5' phosphate from DNA. If I'm using it in the lab on a sample of 1-5 micrograms of digested DNA, how would I figure out how long to incubate the sample at 37 degrees Celsius?

Comment: I typically just react it for an hour, that amount of DNA doesn't seem excessive.

Comment: [This set of protocols](http://labs.biology.ucsd.edu/lykkeandersen/updated%20protocols/Cloning2_updated.htm) was really helpful for me when I got started cloning.

Comment: VTC because not looking up the manufacturer protocol counts in my opinion as an unresearched homework question.

Answer (score 1):

For 5' extensions or blunt ends, incubate the sample for 15 minutes at 37 degrees Celsius.

For 3' extensions, incubate the sample for an hour.

https://www.neb.com/protocols/1/01/01/vector-dephosphorylation-protocol

Comment: Depends on amount of enzyme added.